# Why does Tekka say "where" while Kylo asked "why" he has come?

Tags: meaning-in-context

These are some quotes from Star War The Force Awakens:

> Kylo Ren : Look how old you've become.
>
> Lor San Tekka : Something far worse has happened to you.
>
> Kylo Ren : You know what I've come for.
>
> Lor San Tekka : I know where you come from, before you called yourself "Kylo Ren".

Why does Lor respond "where you come from" whereas he was supposed to confirm to "what I've come from"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tekka is intentionally *rephrasing* the question, using the same pattern with the verb "to come".  It's a common rhetorical device to change the focus of a conversation. Tekka doesn't care about what Ren has come for -- he thinks it's more important to remind Ren what he used to be.

A similar example:

> Bad Guy:  Do you know **who I am**?
>   Good Guy:  I know **who you work for**.

Here Good Guy changes the focus of the question to imply that Bad Guy's name isn't important -- that he only gets his power and authority from his employer.  Good Guy is saying, in effect, that Bad Guy is nobody special -- he would be nothing without his employer to back him up.

Note:  This is the opening scene in *The Force Awakens*, and Tekka's speech (and death) serves mainly to establish Ren's character as a dark Jedi, capable of callous murder, and to [*foreshadow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreshadowing) some later revelation about his origin story.  This foreshadowing adds dramatic tension.